# Can the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction be simulated with the Brusselator?

Tags: kinetics, stoichiometry, theoretical-chemistry

I'm trying to simulate the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction mathematically, with a system of ODEs. I know how to do this with the Oregonator and now I'm looking for another model to simulate the BZ-reaction.

The Brusselator model is often mentioned as a model to simulate an oscillating reaction and now I'm looking for a paper/article that uses the Brusselator to simulate the BZ-reaction. But till now, I have not found much, so I'm wondering if it even is possible to simulate th BZ-reaction with the Brusselator?

If it is possible, can you point me to a paper that uses the Brusselator to simulate the Oregonator?

If not, why can't the BZ-reaction be simulated with the Brusselator? And are there alternative models I can use, besides the Oregonator?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: reference 1 at the end of the Wikipedia page on the Brusselator compares different models so this might be a good place to start.

Comment: There are alternative models based on real chemical species that can be used, I mentioned a few in my answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/79106/how-does-an-oscillating-reaction-work/81924#81924